# rake assets:precompile > Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " padding": expected ";", was ":20px;"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I was running

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Then I get this error stack:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " padding": expected ";", was ":20px;"
(sass):5108
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1278:in `expected'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1208:in `expected'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1203:in `tok!'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:804:in `block in try_declaration'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1254:in `rethrow'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:809:in `try_declaration'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:732:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
/home/ubuntu/auto_ful/path/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:697:in `block_child'
```

But then I tried this to backtrace where exactly the error is:

```
sass -c app/assets/stylesheets/**.css*
```

I get this following error message :

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "#f0f0f0": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 18 of app/assets/stylesheets/ajax-bootstrap-select.css
```

My CSS in ajax-bootstrap-select.css is

```
.bootstrap-select .status {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  clear: both;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: are you trying to compile .SASS file?
if yes - could you please post that file as well?

Comment: hmmm the error looks like it's pointing to the wrong file/line, it's hard to tell, I would move all the files out from that directory and start adding one by one and try compilying it until the error appears

Comment: @arieljuod oops! It seems a hard way to find it out! Do you have any other workaround to fix it?

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalan, no idea, maybe instead of adding one do it like a search algorithm haha, remove half of the files, if the error persist, it's in the half you left, if the error is gone it's in the half you took out. It shouldn't be so long to do that, you will narrow it down very fast.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks Mate! However,I figured out what causes it.

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalan add an answer then, in case someone finds this question, maybe it helps, at least can lead a user in the right direction if you tell how did you solve it.

Comment: @arieljuod - I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in the Rails 5 this error happening. I just ran `rake assets:precompile` and it compiles successfully without error.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, it comes just after your background: #f0f0f0 line:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

If all you're trying to do is change the background colour, try:

```
.bootstrap-select .status {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  clear: both;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

You're just using background, which is shorthand for entering various background attributes at once:

> Background - Shorthand property To shorten the code, it is also
>   possible to specify all the background properties in one single
>   property. This is called a shorthand property.
>
> The shorthand property for background is background:
>
> Example body {
>       background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top; }

Comment: I have changed "background" to "background-color" , But now the different error is showing

`Error: Invalid CSS after "both": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 19 of app/assets/stylesheets/ajax-bootstrap-select.css`